# What if statements with dates

Tags: excel

I would like the following

If q14 is between 1/7/18 and 31/7/18, T14, 0

Q14 =15/2/19

T14 4320

I would expect the answer to be 0

Any ideas how I correctly put this into a formula?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Break it down slightly:

> If `Q14` >= `2018-07-01` And `Q14` <= `2018-07-31` Then `T14`, Otherwise `0`

To make a Date show as a date instead of text, you want to use the `DATE` function, which accepts the Year, Month and Day like so: `DATE(2017, 7, 1)`

The way that "And" is handled in Excel is slightly unusual:  You have an `AND` function, and you pass all of your conditions as arguments:

```
AND(Q14>=DATE(2017, 7, 1), Q14<=DATE(2017,7,31))
```

Then you can add this to a normal `IF` function:

```
=IF(AND(Q14>=DATE(2017, 7, 1), Q14<=DATE(2017,7,31)), T14, 0)
```

(Extra note:  Since a day runs from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`, you usually want to check if you are **before** the **next** day instead of **on** the **current** day, which would be `Q14<DATE(2017, 8, 1)`)

Comment: A very comprehensive answer!

Comment: Thank you.  Worked perfectly :-)  Much appreciated.Tracey

Answer (score 0):

You can just test if between using and
so if Q14 is Greater than (using the date formula) 1st July 2018 and Q14 is less than 31st July 2018.
If true return cell T14 else 0

```
=IF(Q14>=DATE(2018,7,1)&Q14<=DATE(2018,7,31),T14,0)
```

Comment: Ampersand (`&`) is to concatenate two strings together - perhaps you meant asterisk? (`*`)  Even then, you need to wrap your conditions in brackets so that they evaluate in the correct order: `(Q14>=DATE(2018,7,1)) * (Q14<=DATE(2018,7,31))`